# Check if element is last of the class in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.bird').each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
      if($(this).is(".bird:last")){
        $('#floatingBarsG').remove();
        $('#step0').fadeIn(600);}
    });
})
```

Where I try to do some events if `$(this)` is last element on the page with class `.bird`, and this code doesn't work.

What is wrong?

Comment: why is `load` handler used here

Comment: Try `var $birds = $('.bird').each(function () {
    $(this).load(function () {
        if ($birds.last().is(this)) {
            $('#floatingBarsG').remove();
            $('#step0').fadeIn(600);
        }
    });
})`

Comment: I've posted it as an answer

Comment: I will accept when SoF lets me. Load is used to track that all images of these class are fully loaded before fade in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $birds = $('.bird').each(function () {
    $(this).load(function () {
        if ($birds.last().is(this)) {
            $('#floatingBarsG').remove();
            $('#step0').fadeIn(600);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GuEVd/)

```
$('.bird').click(function () {
    if ($('.bird').length - 1 == $(this).index('.bird')) {
        alert('last')
    }
})
```